# How do I create a flatlist function in ML?

Tags: sml, ml

I am given an exercise that asks me to write a function `flatlist` that takes a list of lists and "flattens" it by returning the concatenation of all the lists in the original list.

For example:

```
flatlist([1,2], [6,7], [9]) = [1,2,6,7,9]
```

The code below is what I tried

```
fun flatlist([]) = []
  | flatlist(a::rest) = (a::rest);
```

I don't get an error message when writing the function, but I'm having issues when I try the function in the REPL and apply the function in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're asked to write is often called `concat` and happens to exist in the standard library under the name `List.concat`. Still, it's a good exercise to write such a recursive function. And your function does indeed type-check and compile, except there's a subtle flaw you haven't discovered yet.

### Something about syntax

To begin with, I might format your first attempt a little differently with regards to whitespace and parentheses:

```
(* Before *)
fun flatlist([]) = []
  | flatlist(a::rest) = (a::rest);

(* After *)
fun flatlist [] = []
  | flatlist (xs :: xss) = xs :: xss
```

The points that come across here are:

- Since the first element is a list itself, I like to give it a plural name, `xs`, and since the rest is a list of lists of things, I like to give it a double-plural name.  But `xs :: rest` would also be fine. Just so we don't confuse the reader with `x`, which is an good name for a singular, arbitrary value.
- The parenthesis around the `[]` pattern is not necessary because `[]` is a single combinator and so needs no disambiguation. However, the pattern `xs :: xss` *does* needs a parenthesis around it, because it contains an infix pattern constructor which takes multiple arguments. If we left it out, like so:

  ```
  fun flatlist [] = []
    | flatlist xs :: xss = xs :: xss
  ```

  we'd get the following warning (in Moscow ML):

  ```
  ! Toplevel input:
  !   | flatlist xs :: xss = xs :: xss
  !                 ^^
  ! Ill-placed infix in a fun clause
  ```
- The parenthesis around the `xs :: xss` *function body*, on the other hand, *doesn't* need a parenthesis because the function body is syntactically reserved for a single expression, and `xs :: xss`. There's no disambiguation necessary here.
- The ending `;` is also not strictly necessary, unless you copy-paste this function into a REPL rather than put it in a file. So as long as your functions are so short you're just copy-pasting them into the REPL to try them out, having the `;` is fine. When you start to build larger functions and you execute a whole file at once, you might as well leave them out.

The main take-away here, which is also related to the problem you're having with applying this function to a value, probably comes from your experience with programming languages for which function application looks like `f(x)` where the parenthesis means "what came just before is the function name, and what came in between is its argument(s).

SML functions are different: Function application, in its simplest form, looks like `f x`. Parentheses are needed to disambiguate, for example, `f (x + 2)` from `(f x) + 2`, but they're not needed to signify that this is function application. The space between the function name and the value takes care of that.

### Analysing your initial solution

The first problem you're experiencing is passing a list of lists to the function. In your example, what you're actually doing is passing a 3-tuple, `(x,y,z)` with `x`, `y` and `z` being lists. The type for this value is `int list * int list * int list` and not `int list list`, which your function `flatlist` expects. This is because parentheses in SML, when there are commas in them, are used to express *tuples* rather than "arguments to a function".

Trying a list of list of integers, this instead gives:

```
- flatlist [[1,2], [6,7], [9]];
> val it = [[1, 2], [6, 7], [9]] : int list list
```

Tada! Wait.

Let's evaluate your first attempt at `flatlist` by hand by reducing a part of the expression at a time to see what's going on. Here I'm deriving the function call one line at a time with `⇒` meaning "reduces to":

```
  flatlist [[1,2], [6,7], [9]]          (* x = [1,2], xs = [[6,7], [9]] *)
⇒ [1,2] :: flatlist [[6,7], [9]]        (* x = [6,7], xs = [[9]] *)
⇒ [1,2] :: [6,7] :: flatlist [[9]]      (* x = [9], xs = [] *)
⇒ [1,2] :: [6,7] :: [9] :: flatlist []  (* base case *)
⇒ [1,2] :: [6,7] :: [9] :: []           (* just another way to write *)
⇒ [[1,2], [6,7], [9]]
```

So your current `flatlist` is a very complicated [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) for lists.

### Hints for a correct solution

So you have basic recursion right, but the operation you need to perform at each recursive state is a little off. It isn't just `xs :: xss` as the function body, since that will produce the exact same output as input. You have to somehow join the elements of the list `xs` with the elements of the next list, recursively for all lists in `xss`.

Hint: The `@` operator (pronounced "append").